# CartoDB Torque viz: make bubbles grow to show intensity/frequency?

Tags: carto, torque

I'm working on a project that maps the places of origin of the "letters to the editor" submitted to a magazine.

I'm using CartoDB's Torque viz to show the evolution of this data through time.

I would like to show that multiple letters originated from the same address by increasing the size of the bubble at that address. For example, the Marker Fill is 4 for one letter from a particular address, 6 for two letters, 8 for three letters, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I might accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new category Torque to change the marker-size and color if you have a limited amount of different categories (in this case, the number of letters).

You just need a column with this number, use it in the Torque Cat wizard, and then you can check in the CartoCSS code the different options. There you'll be able to select width and color for the marker.

This is the easy approach. A more advanced one would be normalizing your data and using a special torque-aggregation-function to get different values for Torque.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great stuff, iriberri--thank you very much for the helpful response.